# Why am i getting a Syntax error using the following code

Tags: sql

I am using the following statement to develop a simple query. Unfortunately I continually get a syntax error when I run the page.
If I take out either of the RaisedInvoice Select or the Transaction Sum elements it works but fails when both are in.
It must be something stupid so, can I please apologise in advance for my silly mistake.

```
SELECT 
RaisedInvoices.[Invoice Number], SUM(Transactions.sellgross) AS SumOfsellgross 
FROM (RaisedInvoices LEFT JOIN Customers ON RaisedInvoices.[Customer WORef] = Customers.WORef) 
LEFT JOIN Transactions ON RaisedInvoices.[Invoice Number] = Transactions.invnumber
```

Comment: PDO doesn't execute your queries. You are getting a Syntax error from your database server.

Comment: Thanks. I did realise that but worded it badly.

Answer (score 2):

You are aggregating one column but not the other one. In this case, you need to include a `GROUP BY` clause with the non-aggregated column(s).

For example:

```
SELECT 
  RaisedInvoices.[Invoice Number], -- not aggegated
  SUM(Transactions.sellgross) AS SumOfsellgross -- aggregated
FROM RaisedInvoices 
LEFT JOIN Customers 
      ON RaisedInvoices.[Customer WORef] = Customers.WORef
LEFT JOIN Transactions 
      ON RaisedInvoices.[Invoice Number] = Transactions.invnumber
GROUP BY RaisedInvoices.[Invoice Number] -- added GROUP BY here
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query, I would say that you don't need the join with the Customers table.

Here is how I would write it:

```
$query = "SELECT RaisedInvoices.[Invoice Number], SUM(Transactions.sellgross) AS SumOfsellgross FROM RaisedInvoices LEFT JOIN Transactions ON RaisedInvoices.[Invoice Number] = Transactions.invnumber";
```

However, I'm not sure that the brackets syntax is something that the PDO will accept.